# Regex to replace all special characters except asterisk and escaped asterisk

Tags: java, regex, groovy, regexp-replace

I am looking for a regex to replace all special characters except `*` and `\*`.
This regex snippet `input.replaceAll('/[^a-zA-Z0-9*]*/', '')` converts all other characters except `*`, But I am trying to ignore `\*` as well.

`input.replaceAll('/[^a-zA-Z0-9*\\\*]*/', '')` ignores `\*` but it also ignores `\` individually, I am trying to get an expression that considers `\*` as a combination and replaces rest.

Comment: there is no such character as `\*`

Comment: Lets say you have text like ``*,\*,\\*``. Should replacement result be ``*\**`` or ``*\*\*`` or maybe something else?

Comment: @Pshemo it should be `*\*\*`

Comment: Not groovy dev but in Java you could probably use something along ``replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9\\\\*]|\\\\(?![*])", "")``. In short: (rule 1) remove every *single characters* except `a-z` `A-Z` `0-9` ``\`` ``*`` (rule 2) remove ``\`` only if it is not followed by `*`.

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo for the regex and explanation, that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this expression:

```
(?:(?!\\\*)(?!\*)(?![a-zA-Z0-9]).)+
```

See the demo here: https://regexr.com/50t1o